# Install npm and bower packages from the code

Tags: node.js, npm

I have both files(package.json and bower.json) as i wanted. I want to run npm install and bower install from javascript server side file(for example routes.js). I found something like `npm-install` from npm packages but cant figure it out. I dont care how to do that, just have to do that from the javascript.

Comment: Have you taken a look at using a [postinstall script](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/misc/npm-scripts.html)?

Comment: That about script, but how i can start that script from the code?

Comment: It'd be better to know what problem you're trying to solve, exactly. You wouldn't usually run an `npm install` from within your application, unless you're trying to solve a very unique problem. Can you explain what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I have to generate webpage code, and i want to install packages after i generate package.json file.

Comment: npm is a nodejs package, just like any other. If you install the npm package locally, and do a `var npm = require('npm');` you can access all of it's API, including the install. See [this section of their README](https://github.com/npm/npm#using-npm-programmatically) for details.

Comment: I guess that is the answer for npm. Bower dont support such a thing  as i can see.